# How can I deeplink through install from a twitter post to content in my mobile app? Any way to track those installs that come from tweets?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to drive more downloads and engagement using Twitter. Right now I can have people post install links but it just takes them to the app store and I lost all the contextual data about them. Anyone know how to send the tweet information and deeplink data from twitter through the app store into the app?

Comment: Can't be done, to my knowledge.

Comment: I have written a detailed solution document under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266797/deeplink-solution-for-ios-and-android-apps-works-in-facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Austin from Branch here. The technology you're referring to is [Contextual Deeplinking](https://blog.branch.io/in-deeplinking-context-matters/), and Branch is a leader in the space.

You can use Branch to create deeplinks that work through install by dropping in the SDK inside your app and then signing up and putting in some credentials on the dashboard.

The iOS and Android SDKs allow users to share deeplinks over Twitter that will retain context through install, so people clicking on those links who don’t already have your app installed will be prompted to download, and then continue to the original link content in your app after the download finishes. The tech works by embedding params in a simple data dictionary behind a short URL, dropping this as a cookie on the BNC servers, then using some clever matching, they fingerprint and find the right user to pull down this data from within the app (hence the need for their SDK inside the app).

This should help improve engagement with new users. And Branch provides tracking for the clicks/installs coming from those tweeted links (and from all other links created with our SDK), so you’ll know exactly where your new users are coming from.

More details: https://dev.branch.io